# GIF only shows the first frame - PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
dye = Image.open(gif_filename)
img = Image.open(jpg_filename)
frames = []                                                                                                           
    for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(dye):                                                                             
        frame = frame.convert("RGBA").copy()                                                                             
        frame.paste(img, (0,0), img)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        frames.append(frame)                                                                                                                                                                                           
    frames[0].save('character.gif', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:])

character = Image.open('character.gif')
```

character is supposed to be a gif, but it just returns the first frame of the gif.

Comment: Why do you import `dye` and `img` separately, but load the identical thing? When you call `frame.paste(img, (0,0), img)        ` in the for loop, you're not iterating on `img` so you're passing `img` over and over. Is that what you intend?

Comment: @BLimitless dye and img are different things. dye is the background, a gif, and img is a jpg image that I'm pasting onto dye

Comment: got it, thanks, though I now I understand your confusion. Updated the question to make clear you're not just pasting an identical jpg on top of itself over and over in the for loop, and good luck!

Comment: Can't reproduce. Input (GIF): https://i.stack.imgur.com/66XMv.gif Input (static image): https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWavI.png Your code, but with `img = Image.open(...).resize((100, 100)).convert('RGBA')` to get a proper image mask. Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW9hO.gif Provide a full [mre] including your GIF and image for further investigation.